# Why the jaxb documented property com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders is not recognized but the "internal" one does?

Tags: jaxb

I'm confused about the [JAXB 2.2.11 documentation](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch05.html#xmldecl)  where the property is described as `com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders` but when I try it:

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders
```

But using `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders` (note: `internal`) works.

So my question is really about the rationale of this. Am I looking at the wrong documentation? Where is the `internal` coming from?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    MyElement myxml = new MyElement();
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyElement.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

    marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders","");
    //marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders","<DOCTYPE>");

    marshaller.marshal(myxml, System.out);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that right implementation of JAXB is on the classpath. Apparently there are several "reference implementations" to choose from apart from the one shipped with the JDK.

Property: `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders`

- JDK 8 version
- `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11`

Property: `com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders`

- `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.2.11`
- `com.sun.xmlbind:jaxb-core:2.2.11` plus `com.sun.xmlbind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11`

If you are using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Supports `com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders` (no `internal`).

Or if you use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

You also get `com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders`.

But if you use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

You only get `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders`.

All of them are JAXB 2.2.11 but from different vendors/providers so they differ in things like the marshaller properties supported (since some of them are really not part of the JAXB specification).